# Timezone name not given as expected

Tags: datetime, python-3.7, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a number of imported timestamps with a format like:
`"Wed Nov 13 2019 10:52:24 GMT-0500 (EST)"`
Which according to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) follows the formatting:
`"%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)"`, where `%Z` should be the timezone name: *(empty), UTC, EST, CST*

Trying to interpret a date string with that format will however cause a value error

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("Wed Nov 13 2019 10:52:24 GMT-0500 (EST)",
                           "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)")
:
ValueError: time data 'Wed Nov 13 2019 10:52:24 GMT-0500 (EST)' does not match format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)'
```

To try and fins out what was wrong, I checked the resulting format of a new `now()` call and found that the formatting of the `%Z` is not what I expected

```
datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=-5)))\
                      .strftime("%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)")
'Tue Nov 26 2019 07:02:17 GMT-0500 (UTC-05:00)'
```

As you can see, what I expected to be given as `EST` has come out as `UTC-05:00`.
Does anyone know why that is and/or how I can get the expected output?